# Do nothing if the chosen element is visible, scroll to it if not

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a `<div>` with a scrollbar, I would like to **do nothing if the chosen element is already visible, and scroll to it if the element is not visible yet.**

```js
$('.button').click(function() {
   var selected = '#c' + $(this).attr('id');
   console.log(selected);
   //$(selected).???
} 
);
```

```css
#b { height:120px; width: 200px; overflow:auto; background-color: blue;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="b">
<p id="c1">hello</p>
<p id="c2">hello2</p>
<p id="c3">hello3</p>
<p id="c4">hello4</p>
<p id="c5">hello5</p>
<p id="c6">hello6</p>
<p id="c7">hello7</p>
</div>
<div class="button" id="2">click here to show "hello2"</div>
<div class="button" id="6">click here to show "hello6"</div>
```

Comment: This seems trivial to work out yourself when separating the task into its two components: finding out whether an element is visible (Google e.g. `jquery find out if element is visible`) and scrolling it into view (Google e.g. `jquery scroll element into view`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Updated to not, as commented, scroll all page*

It could be as simple as this

```js
$('.button').click(function() {
  scrollChildIntoView( $('#c' + $(this).attr('id'))[0] );  
});

function scrollChildIntoView(el) {
  el.parentElement.scrollTop = el.offsetTop - (el.offsetHeight/2);
}
```

```css
#b { height:120px; width: 200px; overflow:auto; background-color: blue;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="b">
<p id="c1">hello</p>
<p id="c2">hello2</p>
<p id="c3">hello3</p>
<p id="c4">hello4</p>
<p id="c5">hello5</p>
<p id="c6">hello6</p>
<p id="c7">hello7</p>
</div>
<div class="button" id="2">click here to show "hello2"</div>
<div class="button" id="6">click here to show "hello6"</div>
```

Or check it first (whole element should be in view)

```js
$('.button').click(function() {
  if (!isChildScrolledIntoView( $('#c' + $(this).attr('id'))[0] )) {
    scrollChildIntoView( $('#c' + $(this).attr('id'))[0] );  
  }
});

function isChildScrolledIntoView(el) {
  return ((el.getBoundingClientRect().top >= 0) && (el.getBoundingClientRect().bottom <= el.parentElement.offsetHeight));  
}
function scrollChildIntoView(el) {
  el.parentElement.scrollTop = el.offsetTop - (el.offsetHeight/2);
}
```

```css
#b { height:120px; width: 200px; overflow:auto; background-color: blue;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="b">
<p id="c1">hello</p>
<p id="c2">hello2</p>
<p id="c3">hello3</p>
<p id="c4">hello4</p>
<p id="c5">hello5</p>
<p id="c6">hello6</p>
<p id="c7">hello7</p>
</div>
<div class="button" id="2">click here to show "hello2"</div>
<div class="button" id="6">click here to show "hello6"</div>
```

Or check it first (partial in view)

```js
$('.button').click(function() {
  if (!isPartialChildScrolledIntoView( $('#c' + $(this).attr('id'))[0] )) {
    scrollChildIntoView( $('#c' + $(this).attr('id'))[0] );  
  }
});

function isPartialChildScrolledIntoView(el) {
  return ((el.getBoundingClientRect().top < el.parentElement.offsetHeight) && (el.getBoundingClientRect().bottom > 0));  
}
function scrollChildIntoView(el) {
  el.parentElement.scrollTop = el.offsetTop - (el.offsetHeight/2);
}
```

```css
#b { height:120px; width: 200px; overflow:auto; background-color: blue;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="b">
<p id="c1">hello</p>
<p id="c2">hello2</p>
<p id="c3">hello3</p>
<p id="c4">hello4</p>
<p id="c5">hello5</p>
<p id="c6">hello6</p>
<p id="c7">hello7</p>
</div>
<div class="button" id="2">click here to show "hello2"</div>
<div class="button" id="6">click here to show "hello6"</div>
```

Comment: Your code also scrolls the whole page. I think the OP wants only the div to scroll...

Comment: @Flyer53 Yeah, can see that one's coming so I updated my answer ... thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you.

```js
$('.button').click(function() {
   var id = $(this).attr('id');
   var selected = '#c' + id;
   $('#b').scrollTop(36 * (--id));
} 
);
```

```css
#b { height:120px; width: 200px; overflow:auto; background-color: yellow;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="b">
<p id="c1">hello1</p>
<p id="c2">hello2</p>
<p id="c3">hello3</p>
<p id="c4">hello4</p>
<p id="c5">hello5</p>
<p id="c6">hello6</p>
<p id="c7">hello7</p>
</div>
<div class="button" id="1">click here to show "hello1"</div>
<div class="button" id="2">click here to show "hello2"</div>
<div class="button" id="3">click here to show "hello3"</div>
<div class="button" id="4">click here to show "hello4"</div>
<div class="button" id="5">click here to show "hello5"</div>
<div class="button" id="6">click here to show "hello6"</div>
<div class="button" id="7">click here to show "hello7"</div>
```

Comment: Please also consider when posTop < 0

Comment: Interesting solution, but sadly, 36 is hardcoded, so it wouldn't work if each div has a different height. Another little issue is that I preferred `Do nothing if the chosen element is visible`, so it shouldn't move when clicking on `click here to show "hello2"`.

Comment: Yep! Not a very sophisticated solution with lots of room for improvement. But better than nothing ... and you seem to have got your solution. That's what counts ...